# Remove Unused Resources before shipping

Tags: android, resources

Question:

Does anyone have a quick way for removing all the extra resources in an Android application that are not being used(referenced) in my code?

Explanation:

I've noticed that once I finally get one of my Android applications ready to ship, there are usually a lot of unwanted resources within my application.  I usually have some extra drawables that aren't being used because I switched them out with new ones. I also have extra String resources and even some extra layouts that aren't used anywhere in my application (there is no reference to them in the java code).   I want my applications to take up the least amount of space possible on the user's phone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the ADT in Eclipse includes something called "android lint".

> http://tools.android.com/tips/lint

In a nutshell, it points out problems with your app. One thing it notes is unused resources. It doesn't automatically remove them.

You can access it from Eclipse through (right click project) > android tools > run lint.

Comment: lint does many different checks. if you want only check for unused resources you can do that on the command line: lint --check UnusedResources projectdir

Comment: Lint produces for my project lots of false positives, which is annoying and makes it unusable for me.

Answer (score 2):

besides the builtin Lint: http://code.google.com/p/android-unused-resources/

it can't remove them automatically but it should be able to tell you which resources are unused.

Answer (score 0):

We build a small tool that will remove all the unused resources from your project based on the android lint output. We think this is more reliable then the `android-unused-resources` project as we rely on the official lint tool.

https://github.com/KeepSafe/android-resource-remover

Comment: I’ve encountered a few issues with `android-resource-remover`. It doesn’t seem to do a great job catching errors at the moment. Can’t get it to work and I don’t have the time to dabble with it.

Comment: @MikeMeyer We're using it for our production app and it works nice. It would be nice if you could open a bug report on Github so we can fix the problems you have. Also feel free to open a PR your self. It's a open source project at the end :)

Comment: @phillipp  Can you please give a details on how can i really android resource remover. I set up python. It comes with pip. then i run this command from cmd       setx PATH "%PATH%";C:\Python34\Scripts   for pip and it was saved successfully. Then what should i do. Please please help me on that

Comment: I've never used it with Windows. I'm sorry